# Multiple users login & Performing different tasks using selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, load, testng

My requirement is that 10 different users should be able to login to a particular website and perform different tasks and then after 1 hour all the users should logout simultaneously.

Can this be automated using selenium +testng??
If not,which tool can I use for this particular Load Testing??

Comment: You can do it with Selenium, although maybe it is not the best tool for that - running 10 browser instances takes its toll. I would check on JMeter for example to perform such tests.

Comment: I am also trying to learn JMeter. Thanks for reply